# Merging two database in JIRA

Tags: jira, jira-plugin, jira-agile

I want to merge 2 databases in JIRA Software. One database table has mapping with other database table. It is possible to import data from 2 database but I am not able to show results from both together. Is there any way to work on this?

Comment: What do you want to accomplish by merging the databases exactly?

Comment: I have 2 teams, one is managing bugs in Trac system and another is managing in Bugzilla system. Trac system has one buzilla id field that is the key to map db with Bugzilla system. I want to make one common system in JIRA where records from both systems are visible mapped via Bugzilla id.

Comment: I thought you wanted to migrate 2 jira systems into one. In your case you may want to create a new project (or one project per  system, trac and bugzilla) and just export the tickets from trac and bugzilla as new issues. Maybe it's possible to use an application link or maybe there is an option in trac or bugzilla to export to jira. Whats your approach so far? you need to provide more details

Comment: Thanks for reply Goot!!   We can export to JIRA from both trac and bugzilla as new tickets but problem is i am not able to map them as common tickets according to their relationship as i mentioned before. If i first export tickets of Trac to Jira and then Bugzila to Jira, Bugzila tickets will be added below Trac tickets as new ones, they are not being mapped.
I also try to create 2 projects in Jira and export Trac and Bugzila tickets separately and then write query to map tickets from 2 projects but it does not seems to possible to write qurey to perform join on 2 projects in Jira.

Comment: Now i am going to create a temporary db that will sync records from both Trac and Bugzilla and this db will communicate with JIRA.

Comment: Do you want to merge the content of the two tickets into one JIRA ticket or do you want to create a JIRA ticket which links to the related trac and bugzilla tickets?

Comment: I want to merge content of the 2 tickets into one JIRA ticket.